# What is the one word for saying 'based a template on'?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

If someone, person A, has done really well in their business, and one wants to encourage others to do the same, they would say

....... person A, you should also design a creative product.

What is the word before person A? Where person A is the person one aspires to become (i.e. the inspiration)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a template for something, you are said to [**model**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/model) it:

[Merriam-Webster]

> **1** : to plan or form after a pattern : SHAPE
>   // legislative institutions primarily *modeled* on the English pattern
>   **3 b** :  to produce a representation or simulation (see simulation sense 3a) of
>   // using a computer to *model* a problem
>    4 : to construct or fashion in imitation of a particular model
>   // *modeled* its constitution on that of the U.S.

So, your sentence would be:

> *Modelling* person A, you should also design a creative product.

---

Note, however, that while I believe this is the best answer in terms of a *template* for something (as indicated in the title of your question), other words might better fit the example sentence in the body of your question.

As suggested by some comments under your question, you could use non-template words such as *following*, *emulating*, *duplicating*, or *as with*. (Some senses of those words do have the same meaning as *template*, but others don't.)

Comment: Sure, could be emulating, also.